# rsyslog not creating log file

Tags: syslog, rsyslog

Currently, all my syslogs are logged into `/var/log/syslog` , And I want `local1.*` to go to separate log file.

My `rsyslog.d/50-default.conf` file looks as follows:

```
#  Default rules for rsyslog.
#
#      For more information see rsyslog.conf(5) and /etc/rsyslog.conf

#
# First some standard log files.  Log by facility.
#
auth,authpriv.*                 /var/log/auth.log
*.*;auth,authpriv.none          -/var/log/syslog
#cron.*                         /var/log/cron.log
#daemon.*                       -/var/log/daemon.log
kern.*                          -/var/log/kern.log
#lpr.*                          -/var/log/lpr.log
mail.*                          -/var/log/mail.log
#user.*                         -/var/log/user.log
local1.*                        -/mnt/log/*/*/python/syslog-analytics.log
```

But, `syslog-analytics.log` file is not getting created in the desired location.

Later, I also created that file manually with syslog:adm as the user:group, but still all my logs are logged into `/var/log/syslog`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem - rsyslogd was creating files under /var/log/ and /tmp/ but refused to create files in /data/log/ or log into those files when I created them manually. File systems permissions were never an issue, everything was world-writeable. This almost drove me mad until I found out that I am on an selinux enforced system (CentOS) where some processes are restricted to certain file system locations.

If you don't care for selinux or want to check if this is the cause of your problems simply turn it off by setting SELINUX=disabled in /etc/selinux/config (needs a reboot!).